# Previous songs plays whenever clicked on the Next button rapidly. (flutter assets audio player)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Framework : Flutter
Platform : Android
Plugin : assets_audio_player
issue : Whenever I'm tapping on the next button (rapidly) the previous songs also playing , So I'm getting multiple songs played at a time. Otherwise on normal tap it is working fine.

Here is the code for all buttons ..

```
  void next() async {
await audioPlayer.pause().then((value) => audioPlayer.next());


}
 void prev() async {
    await audioPlayer.pause().then((value) => audioPlayer.previous());
  }

  void pause() async {
    await audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  void play() async {
    await audioPlayer.play();
  }
```

and here is the full code ..

```
class AudioManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  late AssetsAudioPlayer audioPlayer;
  late NotificationSettings _settings;
  late Playlist playlist;

  AudioManager() {
    _init();
    _initSettings();
  }

  void _init() async {
    audioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer.withId('swaraa');
    audioPlayer.playlistFinished.listen((finish) {
      if (finish && playlist.audios.isNotEmpty) {
        resetPlaylist();
      }
    });
  }

 

  void next() async {
    await audioPlayer.pause().then((value) => audioPlayer.next());
  }

  void prev() async {
    await audioPlayer.pause().then((value) => audioPlayer.previous());
  }

  void pause() async {
    await audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  void play() async {
    await audioPlayer.play();
  }

  void addAndPlay({required List<Song> songs, int? index}) async {
    List<Audio> _audios = [];
    for (Song song in songs) {
      _audios.add(
        Audio.network(
          song.url,
          metas: Metas(
            album: song.album,
            artist: song.singers.join(' , ').toString(),
            image: MetasImage.network(song.coverUrl),
            title: song.title,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    playlist = Playlist(audios: _audios, startIndex: index ?? 0);
    audioPlayer.open(
      playlist,
      autoStart: true,
      notificationSettings: _settings,
      showNotification: true,
    );
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    audioPlayer.dispose();
  }

  void _initSettings() {
    _settings = const NotificationSettings(
      nextEnabled: true,
      prevEnabled: true,
      stopEnabled: false,
      seekBarEnabled: true,
      playPauseEnabled: true,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution from github and it worked for me :

```
bool nextDone = true;
bool prevDone = true;
void next() async {
    if (nextDone) {
      nextDone = false;
      await audioPlayer.next();
      nextDone = true;
    }
  }

  void prev() async {
    if (prevDone) {
      prevDone = false;
      await audioPlayer.previous();
      prevDone = true;
    }
  }
```